# I have the following code and want to extract the titles for the courses but it seems that does not work. Or am i missing something

Tags: python

I have this code that it's **scraping** the a particular page for extracting names for the courses that the site provide.

```
   import requests
   import sys
   import lxml.html
   import requests
   import os.path
   url = sys.argv[1]
   #url = input("Please enter the url for course: ")
   page = requests.get(url)
   tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
   names = tree.xpath('//div[@class="topic-title"]/text()')
   names = filter(lambda n: n.strip(), names)
   table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('?:/'))
   for index, name in enumerate(names): 
   os.mkdir('INE - {}'.format(name.strip().translate(table)))
```

It must to extract names from here :

https://my.ine.com/course/ine-ccie-spv41-mpls-l3vpn-over-dmvpn/26ec3c63-c51a-49c4-bd9e-9f1034faab4f

CiscoMPLS L3VPN over DMVPNThis section covers implementing MPLS Layer 3 VPNs over DMVPN.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eh... what is your question? Is your code not working? If not, in which way does it fail?

Comment: Hello Sir. Yes, the code it is not working. When I execute the code does nothing that it's supposed to do. Thank you!

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, by editing it. Describe _exactly_ what the code is supposed to do, and what it does instead. If you cannot pin it down to a single problem, the pick the first problem and ask a question only about that.

Comment: The page that i've provided earlier it have the following code in html :

<h4 class="course-title">MPLS L3VPN over DMVPN</h4>

So i need to extract "course-title" name which is MPLS L3VPN over DMVPN. The script that i have, does not do that and i don't know where i am wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add all relevant information *to the question* instead of writing comments.